# COALESCE function is not working when I pass NULL values but it works when declare variables as NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I execute the following query,I am getting the output, but when I pass `NULL` parameter, it is not working.

**Example 1:**

```
DECLARE 
@a int = NULL,
@b int = NULL,
@c int = NULL
SELECT COALESCE(@a, @b,@c)
GO
```

> Output: NULL

**Example 2:**

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULL, NULL,NULL)
GO
```

> Output: At least one of the arguments to COALESCE must be an
>   expression that is not the NULL constant.

***Can someone explain, why example 1 is working but example 2 not.***

Comment: Is anything unclear about the error message? SQL Server can deduce a type in the first case (`int`) but not the second. The only scenario where I can think of where this could possibly matter is if you're auto-generating expressions with replacement. In which case, make sure to always add a dummy `CONVERT(INT, NULL)` as the first argument and you'll be fine. (Well -- provided you're always passing `INT`s, otherwise you can run into conversion issues.)

Comment: I bet it has to do with SQL not knowing the proper types. `SELECT COALESCE(CAST(NULL AS INT), NULL,NULL)` works just fine.

Comment: Try `SELECT COALESCE(cast(NULL as int), NULL,NULL)`. (So that the data type becomes defined.)

Comment: @Caramiriel ya. might be the reason it is throwing exception.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the error is pretty clear:  `coalesce()` "needs" a non-constant argument that is not `NULL`.  So, the grammar has imposed a simple restriction on explicit `NULL`s.  Note that this error is a *compile*-time error, not a *run*-time error.

Your question really seems to be:  "Why does it do the check on explicit `NULL`s but not on variables?"  Because it can easily do the check during the compilation phase.  Although the *compiler* could keep track of the default values in your case, any intermediate assignments would make the problem something that the compiler cannot do.  So, SQL Server simply says "I don't know if a variable is `NULL` or not", and the statement compiles fine.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the error message returned from SQL Server.  At least one of the arguments to COALESCE must be an expression that is not the NULL constant.

I cannot think of a reason, except to test if this error is trapped, to perform the query with multiple NULL values, where no arguments have been included that is not the NULL constant.

What were you trying to achieve?