# Force COALESE(NULL,NULL) to return NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In SQL SERVER 
Considering the fact that:
Col1 and Col2 contain numeric and NULL values

```
SELECT 
COALESCE(Col1,Col2)
```

Return an error: "At least one of the arguments to COALESCE must be an expression that is not the NULL constant." 
Considering that Col1 and Col2 are NULL,I want to force it to return NULL value in this case.

The workaround seems to be unelegant/inefficient for me:

```
SELECT
NULLIF(COALESCE(Col1 ,Col2 ,''),'')
```

Note that Col1 and Col2 are numeric fields and cannot take '' as a value.

Any other suggestion ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: I'm lost.  You would get that error with `coalesce(null, null)`, but not with `coalesce(col1, col2)`:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=20c3de2eb114015392f94a77680ec06f.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you, according to your exemple it resolves my issue !

Comment: If `Col1` or `Col2` are a numerical data type, then `''` (in that expression) won't return a blank string either, it'll return `0` (bceause `''` will be implicitly converted to the highest precedence data type of `Col1` and `Col2`). But Neither `''` or `0` are `NULL`.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51839448

Comment: from MS Docs: "At least one of the null values must be a **typed** NULL."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code works:

```
SELECT COALESCE(Col1, Col2) 
FROM . . .   -- references here that define COL1 and COL2
```

If both columns are `NULL`, it will return `NULL` (typed as an integer in your case).

The only time you get the error you mention is when the columns are *explicitly* `NULL`.  Even calculations seem to get around this:

```
select coalesce(null + 3, null)
--> NULL rather than an error
```

The following even returns `NULL` rather than an error:

```
declare @col1 int;
declare @col2 int;

select coalesce(@col1, @col2);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3f89278581419b5838d2cfffd8c1373d) is a db<>fiddle.